# Call another prompt after submit prompt

Tags: javascript, impromptu

I want to call another prompt after submitting my answer, but the `.prompt` inside `LoadNewRecord` function doesn't show up. Any idea ?

**Submit prompt**:

```
$.prompt("Opening Recap with ID " + Recap[0][0].id + ".<br> Note: Any changes on Recap " + header.find("#recap_id").val() + " will not be saved.", {
  title: "WARNING",
  buttons: {
    "Continue": true,
    "Cancel": false
  },
  submit: function(e, v, m, f) {
    var Recap_status;
    if (v === true) {
      Recap_status = Recap[0][0].status;
      LoadNewRecord(Recap, header);
      return $("#error_history").hide();
    } else {
      return selectedRecap();
    }
  }
});
```

**Prompt in LoadNewRecord function:**

```
if (period_lock >= getDateInput(Recap[0][0].recap_date) && Recap_status < 20) {
  setTimeout((function() {
    $.prompt("You are not allowed to make any changes for all documents before " + period_lock + ". Please contact your administrator for further information");
  }), 100);
}
```

Note: 
I use `setTimeout` after reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049384/jquery-impromptu-callback-issue-prompt-fails), but still doesn't work..

if I remove the `$.prompt` inside `LoadNewRecode` or change it to `alert` everything works fine.

Comment: How you able to access `Recap_status` outside as it's a local variable of submit function

Comment: `Recap_status` is a global variable, for simplicity, everything works fine if I remove the `$.prompt` inside `LoadNewRecode` or change it to `alert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who stuck with this issue, all you need to do is to download the latest impromptu [here](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Impromptu)..

For more details you can refer to [this](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Impromptu/issues/46) post on Github..